# SSMS -- inhibit results or remove temporary files when query is done

Tags: query-performance, ssms, memory, disk-space

I am running several instances of the same query to establish baselines for potential performance optimization.  That is, I want to compare timing for two versions of the same query.

I am using SSMS 18.8 to run the query, the actual db is older still.

I am using a timing paradigm from:
[Timing Paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675077/measure-the-time-it-takes-to-execute-a-t-sql-query)

SSMS will put the results (which I don't need in this context) into either a window or a text-file.
However, either of these options use to much disk-space and sometimes too much memory as well.

- Is there a way to compare the queries without having SSMS show/store
  the results?
- How do I remove any un-needed files that SSMS creates after running
  the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, choose "Query Options" --> select "Results" form the left nav, check "Discard results after execution"

[SSMS discard results after execution reference](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/discarding-results-of-a-query-execution-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

Comment: If anyone reads this, is there a way to set the options in a script, please?