# Inhibiting results to pane in SSMS (TSQL language) via script

Tags: query-performance, t-sql, optimization, ssms

I found that one could use a menu to "discard" results in SSMS (TSQL language).  Please see: [Original Question about inhibiting results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307922/ssms-inhibit-results-or-remove-temporary-files-when-query-is-done) and its answer.

However, I was wondering if there is a script command that will do this, as sometimes I forget to run the command using the windows menu option.

I am using SSMS 18.8 to run the query, the actual db is older still.

PURPOSE:  In this case, I am running several trials of queries to optimize them.  See also:  [Useful optimization link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675077/measure-the-time-it-takes-to-execute-a-t-sql-query)

Comment: There is a related (though I don’t think duplicate) Q&A here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233134/32281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't, because this is a feature of SSMS itself to not render the results to a UI Grid object, not a function of the T-SQL language.

That being said, you can emulate a similar outcome by selecting your results to a local `#TempTable` and then dropping that table right after. Then the SSMS Elapsed Time will match the actual query Execution Time, *most* times. (It isn't a perfect alternative, if your server faces a lot of `tempdb` contention, but usually that's not the case.)